# How to install and setup GIT for Qt

Tags: git, qt, version-control

I'm trying to put my current project on version control. With java, I've been using SVN because it has a very easy and intuitive plugin for eclipse. The current project I'm working on, is a Qt project. I'm using Qt Creator as my IDE. I am developing on Windows 7, and am using the Qt v. 4.7.4. I have come to the conclusion that GIT is the optimal choice of version control for Qt. My questions are: How can I set up a GIT repository on my server? How can i connect to it from QtCreator (remote computer)?

please note, I'm working under the assumption that GIT is the best solution. If it turns out that there is an easier alternative such as SVN, mercurial etc... please share that as well.

Comment: I am assuming you read the gitbook http://book.git-scm.com/

Comment: I don't mean to be unhelpful, but have you considered just using it from the command line? That's the de facto interface to Git (and most VCSs), and I found it to be the only way to really learn how it works.

Comment: @farbrizio I started the gitbook, but it showed command line instructions, and also instructions requiring me to compress my project to a .tar.gz.

Comment: @WillVousden I would prefer to use it through the IDE, it makes life much simpler...but if the 'right' way to learn is through the command prompt, then I guess I'll just head in that direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What OS are you on?

Personally on windows I use [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) separate from the IDE

I haven't used any of this but see - [Integrating QtCreator with source control](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.4/creator-version-control.html)

Comment: Mine is OS X Elcaptain (mac) ? I cannot find any proper tutorial on how to setup QT and GitHub. Pleeeeease help